# VBA add rows based on criteria from a different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to `VBA` and would appreciate some assistance.  In this scenario let's say I have `2 worksheets within a workbook`.  The first is labeled `monkeys` and the second is `cows`.

In `cows` I have a number in `cell P1`.  If it is greater than 0, I want to add rows in `monkeys` based on that number.  Specifically add empty rows from row 5 in `monkeys`.

If cell P1 in `cows` is 0, then do nothing.

Please let me know if there are questions.  Appreciate any input.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The object model for sheets shows you how you can test whichever sheet you are after:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193217.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

```
if Sheets("Cows").Cells(1,16).Value > 0 then
  Sheets("Monkeys").Cells/Row/etc...... = Sheets("Cows").Cells/Row/etc.......
End if
```

You may need to also check if the value is numeric: isNumeric(x) tests if a value is numeric or not.